# What does += mean

Tags: python, syntax

`some_product += another_product`

I have just started learning python so I am very new to the language, and I am struggling to understand what += means.

Comment: Same as `some_product = some_product + another_product`.

Comment: Did you try something like `a = 1
a += 2
print(a)`?

Comment: If only there was some sort of documentation which told you how these things? Oh, wait, there is: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html - more specifically, for your question: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a very simple example of how to add to a variable a number:

```
a = 1
# we want to add to a 5
a = a + 5
print(a)
# output: 6
```

or:

```
a = 1
a += 5 # equivalent with a = a + 5
print(a)
# output: 6
```

similar: 
`some_product += another_product` is equivalent with: `some_product = some_product + another_product`, assuming that your variables are integers or other numeric types

Comment: That's a good example for integers, however we don't know if OP is talking about integers, strings, lists or custom classes that implement ``__iadd__`` / ``__add__``.

Comment: yep, just updated my answer